# How to adjust different margins between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to adjust the margin between subplots using matplotlib. For example, I have three subplots, 3 rows * 1 column. I want hspace between ax0 and ax1 to be 0, and hspace between ax1 and ax2 to be 0.5.
Use `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` will adjust hspaces to be the same, but I want them to be different. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hspace` argument acts globally on all subplots. To have different hspaces, you may introduce another invisible plot in between the two bottom plots and adjust its height ratio to half of that of the others.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4,
                         gridspec_kw={"height_ratios" : [1,1,.5,1], "hspace":0})

axes[0].tick_params(axis="x", bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
axes[2].axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's just what I want! Thank you very much!